# Worker Class outside ui thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask, worker

I have to make a **massive sql manipulation** (too many inserts) at the beginning of the app. I have a splash screen like this.

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ...
        new SetupDataBaseWorker(this).execute();
    }
    private class SetupDataBaseWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private SqliteManager db_sql;
        private Activity activity;

        public SetupDataBaseWorker(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;

            db_sql = new SqliteManager(this.activity);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ...
            showDialogLoading();
            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            ...
            db_sql.inserting();
            ...
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            this.activity.startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            this.activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

1- Always at the first running (after install), i got a blank screen for 10 seconds (i suppose that's the script running...), and after, my app goes to the mainActivity.

2- If i run the app a second time, it shows a blank screen for 1 seconds and goes to the MainActivity (Don't even shows the SplashScreen layout).
It seems that the worker class it's not working outside the ui thread at all... What i have to do to accomplish that? I already tried put this worker at a Service, but still the same.

Comment: In the onResume() you are using `SetupDataBaseWorker().execute();` and not this `new SetupDataBaseWorker(this).execute();` and this is not called `db_sql = new SqliteManager(this.activity);` or am I wrong?

Comment: `showDialogLoading` does that method work and actually shows a loading dialog?

Comment: Guys, this is an *abstraction*... The whole code is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing everything in the Background Thread then Main Thread not at all blocked.

I am also doing same thing "copying the database from assets folder to DB" in the Splash activity I am not getting anything like you.

It is IDE "issue", Android studio takes more time than the Eclipse to install the application into device.

You just try once "Copy the APK into device and install from the device itself".

I was also assuming same like you. but the problem is regarding "IDE" not related to our code or Android.

Comment: Perferct... You're right. I did this and voilà, got it done :).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
public SetupDataBaseWorker(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    db_sql = new SqliteManager(this.activity);
}
```

move initializer into

```
public SetupDataBaseWorker(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;    
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void...urls) {
    ...
    db_sql = new SqliteManager(this.activity);
    db_sql.inserting();
    ...
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @MachoProgrammer, nice avatar cat;)